# Ошибка "proxy" objects is not callable, как исправить?

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *
import time
import random

f = open('udemy_titles', 'a', encoding='utf8')
file = open("input_1.txt", 'r')
login_pass_dict = dict()
for x in [line.strip().split(':') for line in file]:
    login_pass_dict.update({x[0]: x[1]})

for login, password in login_pass_dict.items():

    f.write("\n" + "USERNAME: ")
    f.write(login + "\n")
    f.write("PASSWORD: ")
    f.write(password + "\n")

    myProxy = random.choice(open('proxy.txt').readlines())
    Proxy = Proxy({
        'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
        'httpProxy': myProxy,
        'httpsProxy': myProxy,
        'ftpProxy': myProxy,
        'sslProxy': myProxy,
        'noProxy': ''
        })
    print(myProxy + "\n")

    driver= webdriver.Firefox(proxy=Proxy)
    driver.get('https://www.udemy.com')
    print("GOT URL\n")
    time.sleep(5)

    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-purpose='header-login']").click()
    print("OPEN LOGIN FORM\n")
    time.sleep(5)

    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(570, 295).click().send_keys(login).perform()
    print("PRINT MAIL\n")
    time.sleep(5)

    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(100, 65).click().send_keys(password).perform()
    print("PRINT PASSWORD\n")
    time.sleep(5)

    try:
        webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(0, 60).click().perform()
        print("AUTORIZATION\n")
        time.sleep(6)

        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-purpose='my-courses']").click()
        print("GO TO URL\n")
        time.sleep(5)

        def parse_pagination(driver):
            try:

                ul_pagination = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul.pagination.pagination-expanded")
                li_pagination = ul_pagination.find_elements_by_css_selector("li")[-2]
                count_page = int(li_pagination.find_element_by_css_selector("a").text)
                urls = []
                for i in range(2, count_page + 1):
                    urls.append("https://www.udemy.com/home/my-courses/learning/?p=" + str(i))
                    time.sleep(2)
                return urls
            except:
                pass

        def parse_list(driver):
            try:
                div_card_wrapper = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                     EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.card-wrapper")))
                div_cards = div_card_wrapper.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.card.card--learning")
                for div_card in div_cards:
                    a = div_card.find_element_by_css_selector("a.card--learning__details > div > strong")
                    name = a.text
                    print(name)
                    f.write(name + "\n")
            except:
                pass

        try:
            div  = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='pager-label']").text
            div_1 = div.split(" ")[-2]
            f.write("TOTAL COURSES: " )
            f.write(div_1 + "\n")
        except:
            pass

        try:
            parse_list(driver)
            urls = parse_pagination(driver)
            for url in urls:
                driver.get(url)
                time.sleep(2)
                parse_list(driver)
        except:
            pass

        driver.close()
        time.sleep(2)
    except:
        f.write("LOGIN OR PASSWORD IS INCORRECTLY PROVIDED" + "\n")
        driver.close()
        time.sleep(1)

f.close()
file.close()
```

При использовании прокси выбивает ошибку "proxy" objects is not callable, как её можно исправить?

Comment: Ну все правильно. Если переопределяешь функцию, то чего еще ожидать-то?

Comment: PS. Текст ошибки надо копировать, а не перепечатывать.

Answer (score 2):

В этой строчке:

```
Proxy = Proxy({
            'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
            'httpProxy': myProxy,
            'httpsProxy': myProxy,
            'ftpProxy': myProxy,
            'sslProxy': myProxy,
            'noProxy': ''
            })
```

функция `Proxy()` медленно превращается в результат самой себя. И в следующей итерации цикла никакой функции `Proxy()` уже не существует. Нужно переименовать, например:

```
proxy_in_use = Proxy({
           'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
           'httpProxy': myProxy,
           'httpsProxy': myProxy,
           'ftpProxy': myProxy,
           'sslProxy': myProxy,
           'noProxy': ''
           })
```

И дальше, соответственно, тоже:

```
driver= webdriver.Firefox(proxy=proxy_in_use)
```

Comment: Так а что можно сделать, если при каждой последующей авторизации, надо менять прокси?

Comment: Ничего на надо, random.choice() же никуда не делся.